# How meaningful is to pool data from different surveys on the same target population?

Tags: survey, pooling, weighted-data, survey-weights, survey-sampling

Apologies for cross posting

This is a very theoretical question for me but I would like to find an answer as I might want to use this in the (near) future.
In many cases same questions are used in different surveys which are targeted for the same (or almost the same) population (and all designed to give national estimates). However, as most surveys have long time periods between waves, sometimes I would like to compare results from different data sources which, perhaps, have data from two consecutive years.
I have done some basic reading (Korn & Graubard 1999; Thomas 2007) but in many cases they provide examples on how to pool data from different waves of the same survey and, sub-sequentially, how to normalize the weights.
However, many papers open to the possibility to pool data from different data sources, bearing in mind that populations must be comparable and there should be no evident differences in terms of sampling strategy/survey methodology.

But what if surveys have been conducted on the same population and the questions asked are pretty much the same but with the two surveys being conducted with a (slightly) different sampling strategy (e.g. three sampling units vs two sampling units, but both surveys are country representative and have similar sample size)? Is it still meaningful to pool data together? and if so, how should the weights be adjusted? In same cases I read that authors advised to rescale the weights according to the new sample size (or in others to divide the weights by the weights mean in order to de-scale the variable). Not sure if it is the case in this situation as well though. What should you recommend?

I was exploring this possibility because I would be interested in time trend of some estimates, i.e. I might want to look at physical activity in people over 65 yo in the UK using different data sources which would give me the possibility to have at least two data points within 5 years. This to see whether some policies put in place have an impact on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, this might be too theoretical to give a definitive answer on?  might be more useful for you to pose this as a series of more discrete questions, each focused on a specific adjustment you are considering?